# vim and 256 colors in ConEmu

Tags: vim, colors, conemu

I have enabled the 256 colors in ConEmu by using

```
"enable 256 colors in ConEmu on Win
if has('win32') && !has('gui_running') && !empty($CONEMUBUILD)
    set term=xterm
    set t_Co=256
    let &t_AB="\e[48;5;%dm"
    let &t_AF="\e[38;5;%dm"
endif
```

This works properly with my colors schema which is seoul256.
But unfortunatelly it doesn't work with e.g. the [colorizer vim plugin](https://github.com/lilydjwg/colorizer)
I wanted to show the colors from the table under the Web safe colors? section: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp)

What I got is visible at the following screenshot. No problems in gvim as you can see, but in console colors are wrong.

[image]

I have also problems with colors in the vim-powerline or vim-airline plugins also. What I can see, I have no problems only with the colors from my color schema. Why it doesn't work in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recently introduced colorizer bug and should have been fixed just now.

Answer (score 0):

That is colorizer plugin bug. It translates RGB to xterm incorrectly.

You may check that in mintty (cygwin) for example. Same color highlighting.

Report that to plugin author.